# Symfony2: #id in url to focus element

Tags: php, symfony, hyperlink, href

I have this navigation with links like this:
`href="http://mamgrow.lt/veikla.php#konkursai"`

So it opens a page with element with `id='konkursai'` focused.

How can I do this in Symfony?

My pages are created as actions and links to them are described in routing.yml

MainController:

```
public function aboutUsAction() {
    return $this->render('MamgrowMainBundle:Main:about-us.html.twig');
}

public function activitiesAction() {
    return $this->render('MamgrowMainBundle:Main:activities.html.twig');
}

public function contactsAction() {
    return $this->render('MamgrowMainBundle:Main:contacts.html.twig');
}
```

routing.yml:

```
about-us:
    path:     /apie-mus
    defaults: { _controller: MamgrowMainBundle:Main:aboutUs }

contacts:
    path:     /kontaktai
    defaults: { _controller: MamgrowMainBundle:Main:contacts }

activities:
    path:     /veikla
    defaults: { _controller: MamgrowMainBundle:Main:activities }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply append hash part to the generated path/url:

```
<a href="{{ path('contacts') }}#some-anchor">Contact Us</a>
```

Comment: Maybe you know how can I do the same thing, but without #id appearing into url? Focusing element by id, but url stays clean.

Comment: You could scroll page to some ID using JavaScript but you still need to pass that information somehow using URL.

Answer (score 0):

This solutions can help you for statics pages:

```
    static-page:
            path: /website/{page}
            defaults: { _controller: MamgrowMainBundle:Main:static }

        public function staticAction($page) {
            return $this->render('MamgrowMainBundle:Main:'.$page.'.html.twig'');
        }

TwigView.html.twig
    <a href="{{ path('static-page', {"page": "contact-us"} ) }}">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="{{ path('static-page', {"page": "about-us "} ) }}">AboutUs </a>
```

the var "page" has to be named exactly like your views for the staticAction method works fine!!!